# Anyone knows how change package name of Telegram app?

Tags: android, github, package, rename, telegram

I have downloaded the **official Telegram** app avaiable on **GitHub**, but i am not able to **change the Package name** to can upload the app to Google Play (I made some changes in the app).

I've tried to change the name in "org.telegram > refactor > rename" and also to create a new package, and move the content for it.

With the two methods, **the app compile successfully**, but when i install the app and beginning it **show me an error** and not begin.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated the package name in the manifest?

Comment: Yes. But still not working.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: see this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166901/9406623